# disk sector reading in objective c

Tags: macos

I am using this method to access drive and reading sector.

```
int fd = open("/dev/rdisk1s1");
nbytes_got = pread(fd, buf, nbytes, off);
```

but **FD** returns -1 means it failed. i need to read disks and their sectors but i am unable to do this in mac OS X. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `open` returns `-1`, then you need to check `errno` to see why it failed.  The most likely reason is that you are not running your program as `root` or as a user in group `operator`.

Also, you are missing the second (`oflag`) parameter to the `open` function.

That is pretty basic knowledge.  Reading disk sectors directly is generally a pretty advanced topic.  You probably shouldn't be doing this at your level of knowledge.